# pyspark: how to specify rebalance partitioning hint with columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

How do I specify the [`REBALANCE` partitioning hint](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html#partitioning-hints) with column names using the **pyspark** APIs?

As an example, let's assume we have

```
df = spark.range(10)
```

The following attempt fails:

```
>>> df.hint("rebalance", "id").explain()
...
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: REBALANCE Hint parameter should include columns, but id found
```

How do I specify the columns if not by name, i.e. a simple string?

- Using an alias doesn't work either

  ```
  >>> df.alias("df").hint("rebalance", "df.id").explain()
  ...
  pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: REBALANCE Hint parameter should include columns, but df.id found
  ```
- Nor does using a column reference

  ```
  >>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
  >>> df.hint("rebalance", F.col("id")).explain()
  TypeError: all parameters should be in (<class 'str'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'int'>), got Column<'id'> of type <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
  ```

Note that specifying the rebalance hint **without** columns works just fine but is not what I'm looking for:

```
>>> df.hint("rebalance").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(4), REBALANCE_PARTITIONS_BY_NONE, [id=#551]
   +- Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research and this appears to be a bug in Spark (more or less).
The column names are never converted into `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression` as they are in `df.repartition`.

Even in Scala, passing a string causes the same exception:

```
scala> df.hint("rebalance", "id")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: REBALANCE Hint parameter should include columns, but id found
```

So does passing the column (surprisingly):

```
scala> df.hint("rebalance", $"id")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: REBALANCE Hint parameter should include columns, but id found
```

But getting the column's expression works:

```
scala> df.hint("rebalance", $"id".expr)
res10: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]
```

I'm going to raise an issue on the main Spark project about this and will update this answer with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked in Pyspark.

```
df.hint("rebalance(id)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue where you can't use a column with the `rebalance` hint is still present in PySpark 3.4.0.

A workaround is to submit an SQL query directly through the Spark session.

For example:

```
df = spark.range(10)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('dftempview')
df_rebalanced = spark.sql("SELECT /*+ REBALANCE(id) */ * FROM dftempview;")
```